# Multi-Threading Cross-Class Cancellation with TPL

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, cancellation

All, I have a long running process that I run on a background thread (with cancellation support) using the Task Paralell Library (TPL). The code for this long running taks is contained within `Class Validation`, and when the method

```
public bool AsyncRunValidationProcess(TaskScheduler _uiScheduler, 
    CancellationToken _token, dynamic _dynamic = null)
{
    try
    {

        // Note: _uiScheduler is used to update the UI thread with progress infor etc.

        for (int i = 0; i < someLargeLoopNumber; i++)
        {
            // Cancellation requested from UI Thread.
            if (_token.IsCancellationRequested) 
                _token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        // Do stuff. Display `eX` if cancellation requested.
        return false;
    }
}
```

is run from `Class Validation` I can cancel the process fine. The cancellation request is handled by the appropriate `delegate` (shown below) and this works fine (I don't belive this is the cause of my problem).

When I run this method from another class, `Class Batch`, I do this via a "controller" method

```
asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => asyncControlMethod(), token);
```

which in turn invokes the method

```
valForm.AsyncRunValidationProcess(uiScheduler, token, 
    new List<string>() { strCurrentSiteRelPath }));
```

where `valForm` is my accessor to `Class Validation`, the method runs fine, but when I attempt a cancellation the `delegate`

```
cancelHandler = delegate 
{
    UtilsTPL.CancelRunningProcess(asyncTask, cancelSource);
};
```

where

```
public static void CancelRunningProcess(Task _task, 
    CancellationTokenSource _cancelSource)
{
    try
    {
        _cancelSource.Cancel();
        _task.Wait(); // On cross-class call it freezes here.
    }
    catch (AggregateException aggEx)
    {
        if (aggEx.InnerException is OperationCanceledException)
            Utils.InfoMsg("Operation cancelled at users request.");
        if (aggEx.InnerException is SqlException)
            Utils.ErrMsg(aggEx.Message);
    }
}
```

freezes/hangs (with no unhandled exception etc.) on `_task.Wait()`. This (I belive - through testing) is to do with the fact that I am cancelling `asyncControlMethod()` which has called `valForm.AsyncRunValidationProcess(...)`, so it is cancelling `asyncControlMethod()` which is causing the current process to hang. The problem seems to be with passing the `CancellationTokenSource` etc. to the child method. The `IsCancellationPending` event fires and kills the controlling method, which causes the child method to hang.

**Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or (more pertinently), what should I be doing to allow such a cancellation procedure?**

*Note: I have tried to spawn a child task to run `valForm.AsyncRunValidationProcess(...)`, with its own `CancellationToken` but this has not worked.*

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How are you starting the `Task`? Why does your method take a `TaskScheduler` when it doesn't seem to use it?

Comment: It does use it. The passed `TaskScheduler` is for the UI thread. I just have not shown it being used as there is alot of code. It is used to update `DataGridView` and generic GUI controls (progress bar etc.).

Comment: And how are you starting the `Task`?

Comment: Via a generic method which calls `asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => asyncMethod(), token);` to run the specified process/method...

Comment: You havent' provide a complete sample that reproduces the problem.  e.g. there's no code that uses _uiScheduler nor any code that creates/passes it in.  You say the asyncControlMethod invokes AsyncRunValidationProcess; but you don't detail how.  You also haven't show where you create a CancellationToken or even whether the async task uses the same token as the cancellation.

Comment: Why are you creating cancelHandler delegate and how are you invoking it?

Comment: The reason why I have not shown the complete code is two-fold: 1. The complete code listing is large; larger than anyone of SOF will want to peruse. 2. I have narrowed down the error highlighted in the question. The error occurs when I spin off a new thread running method A, and this method invokes method B using the same `CancellationTokenSource`/`CancellationToken`. So the question is why is this happening and what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I have ammended the question to reflect the progress I have made scince this bug first appeared. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Note: I am assigning the cancellation request to a button that may change. This is why I use a delegate to handle this... Thanks again.

Comment: Hanging usually results from deadlock. Looks like you are using a callback to handle cancellation? If so, there are a few guidelines to avoid deadlock as described in [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) (Please pay special attention to the part "**Listening by Registering a Callback**"). Still it's hard to find out what actually causes deadlock without looking at the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem (helped massively by Jiaji Wu's comment and link) was that you cannot declare the `CancellationToken` as a global variable that is passed to the cascading methods; that is, you cannot have

```
public class MainClass
{
    private CancellationTokenSource = source;
    private CancellationToken token;

    public MainClass()
    {
        source = new CancellationtokenSource();
        token = source.Token;
    }

    private void buttonProcessSel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Spin-off MyMethod on background thread.
        Task<bool> asyncControllerTask = null;
        TaskSpin(asyncControllerTask, cancelSource, token, MyMethod);
    }

    private void method()
    {
        // Use the global token DOES NOT work!
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)      
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    private void TaskSpin(Task<bool> asyncTask, CancellationTokenSource cancelSource,
        CancellationToken token, Func<bool> asyncMethod)
    {
        try
        {
            token = cancelSource.Token;
            asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => asyncMethod(token), token);

            // To facilitate multitasking the cancelTask ToolStripButton
            EventHandler cancelHandler = null;
            if (cancelSource != null)
            {
                cancelHandler = delegate
                {
                    UtilsTPL.CancelRunningProcess(mainForm, uiScheduler, asyncTask, cancelSource, true);
                };
            }

        // Callback for finish/cancellation.
            asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                // Handle cancellation etc.
            }

            // Other stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

Use of the global token in the maethod run on the background thread doen NOT work! The method must be explicitly passed the `token` for it to be able to register it. I am not sure of the exact reason why this is the case, but I will know in future, now you need to pass the token to `MyMethod()` like this

```
    private void method(CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Use the global token DOES NOT work!
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)      
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I feel a bit confused as the answer doesn't seem so 'relavant'. Does your code comment 'Use the global token DOES NOT work!' mean that if you use global token, your app hangs at the line `_task.Wait()`? I read the code again in your original question, and here is something I don't quite understand: in method `CancelRunningProcess`, why do you call `_cancelSource.Cancel();`? As `CancelRunningProcess` is the Callback function to be invoked if tasks are cancelled, it should be invoked **after** the call `_cancelSource.Cancel();` (somewhere else in your code).

Comment: I apologise, the question is somewhat poorly posed due to the fact that I initially had a poor response and was editing the question on the fly as I learnt more. I don't need `_task.Wait()` and used it to debug really - ignore this now. Yes, I _was_ using a global `CancellationToken`, and it is _this_ that is not valid. Once I ensured that the token was passed into the various methods they could all be cancelled correctly using a single token and the relevent checks. I hope this clears this up?

Comment: Note. In one class I was using a global token. I then passed this into public method from another class as an argument - this is what caused the issue. Thanks for your time.