# Cancelling a Thread due to hung Db call

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've designed and made a prototype application for a high performance, multi-threaded mail merge to run as a Windows Service (C#). This question refers to one sticky part of the problem, what to do if the process hangs on a database call. I have researched this a lot. I have read a lot of articles about thread cancellation and I ultimately only see one way to do this, thread.Abort(). Yes, I know, absolutely do not use Thread.Abort(), so I have been researching for days how to do it another way and as I see it, there is no alternative. I will tell you why and hopefully you can tell me why I am wrong.

FYI, these are meant as long running threads, so the TPL would make them outside the ThreadPool anyway.

TPL is just a nice wrapper for a Thread, so I see absolutely nothing a Task can do that a Thread cannot. It's just done differently.

Using a thread, you have two choices for stopping it. 
1. Have the thread poll in a processing loop to see if a flag has requested cancellation and just end the processing and let the thread die. No problem.
2. Call Thread.Abort() (then catch the exception, do a Join and worry about Finally, etc.)

This is a database call in the thread, so polling will not work once it is started.

On the other hand, if you use TPL and a CancellationToken, it seems to me that you're still polling and then creating an exception. It looks like the same thing I described in case 1 with the thread. Once I start that database call (I also intend to put a async / await around it), there is no way I can test for a change in the CancellationToken. For that matter, the TPL is worse as calling the CancellationToken during a Db read will do exactly nothing, far less than a Thread.Abort() would do.

I cannot believe this is a unique problem, but I have not found a real solution and I have read a lot. Whether a Thread or Task, the worker thread has to poll to know it should stop and then stop (not possible when connected to a Db. It's not in a loop.) or else the thread must be aborted, throwing a ThreadAbortedException or a TaskCanceledException.

My current plan is to start each job as a longrunning thread. If the thread exceeds the time limit, I will call Thread.Abort, catch the exception in the thread and then do a Join() on the thread after the Abort().

I am very, very open to suggestions... Thanks, Mike

I will put this link, because it claims to do this, but I'm having trouble figuring it out and there are no replys to make me think it will work
[multi-threading-cross-class-cancellation-with-tpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583258/multi-threading-cross-class-cancellation-with-tpl)

Oh, this looked like a good possibility, but I don't know about it either [Treating a Thread as a Service](http://memmove.blogspot.com/2011/04/treating-thread-as-service.html)

Comment: relevant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx

Comment: If the database driver can accept a `CancellationToken`, then it might be able to listen to it and cancel the request gracefully. eg, in SQL Management Studio you can can cancel a running request, so it's not impossible that the ADO.Net driver can do it to. Whether it actually does so is a different matter. If you `Thread.Abort()` then it throws an unstoppable exception, so the driver may or may not be able to cancel in that case.

Answer (score 3):

You can't *actually* cancel the DB operation.  The request is sent across the network; it's "out there" now, there's no pulling it back.  The best you can really do is ignore the response that comes back, and continue on executing whatever code you would have executed had the operation actually completed.  It's important to recognize what this is though; this isn't actually cancelling anything, it's just moving on even though you're not done.  It's a very important distinction.

If you have some task, and you want it to instead become cancelled when you want it to be, you can create a continuation that uses a `CancellationToken` such that the continuation will be marked as canceled when the token indicates it should be, or it'll be completed when the task completes.  You can then use that continuation's `Task` in place of the actual underlying tasks for all of your continuations, and the task will be cancelled if the token is cancelled.

```
public static Task WithCancellation(this Task task
    , CancellationToken token)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(t => t.GetAwaiter().GetResult(), token);
}
public static Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task
    , CancellationToken token)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(t => t.GetAwaiter().GetResult(), token);
}
```

You can then take a given task, pass in a cancellation token, and get back a task that will have the same result except with altered cancellation semantics.

Comment: OK, this might work, but you have given me little to go on. One is a Task, the other is a Task with a TResult. One line of code each, so one line of code to work with.

Comment: @Miguelito You either have a task with a result, or you don't.  You pass in a task of either type, and C#'s overload resolution takes over, using whichever one is appropriate for your context.  If you know that you'll only ever need one, then just use that one.  If you think this might be useful in the future and want to keep it around, keep both around because you don't know if your future tasks will have results or not.  You can now take any task, any task in the world, and provide whatever desired cancellation semantics you want in a wrapper task.

Comment: I meant...OK, you make sense and this might work, but you have given me little to go on. One is a Task, the other is a Task with a TResult. One line of code each, so really one line of code to work with. My understanding is that the taskContinueWith "Creates a continuation that executes asynchronously when the target Task completes." Well, the target Task never completes. Even if I invoke the token, the first Task will never know or be cancelled. If I am wrong, please expand your answer a little. I know that others will want this answer in the future as reading a lot did not show it.

Comment: @Miguelito You are exactly right, the first task will never know that the continuation is cancelled. That's the whole point of my first paragraph.  The inherent operation that your task represents is not cancellable.  There is no way to *actually* cancel it. If there was, then whatever API you're calling that generates the task would need to accept a cancellation token.  The best you can do is create a new task that will be cancelled when you say so, use that new task everywhere instead of the other task, and therefore allow any other continuations to continue when you "cancel" this operation.

Comment: Yesss... But though the operation cannot be cancelled, the Task that called the Db operation is still waiting. I have to make the Task go away. ... OK, so "create a new task that will be cancelled when you say so" ... Ah, I need no continuations after it fails. I need the entire task to end. No data from Db = no further work to do. Log error and go to next job. I'm really trying to understand you, but I don't.

Comment: @Miguelito And to do that all you need to do is create a new task, using a method such as this, and attach all of your continuations involving "going on to the next job" to this wrapper task, rather than the actual underlying task you get from the DB API.  Don't let anyone attach continuations to it; wrap it in a new task with your own cancellation token before ever exposing it to anyone else.

Comment: OK, I'll work on this to see if I can make sense of what you have told me, but I am the only one attaching anything to it... Simple question. If I isolate the Db call into its own Task and that is all it does, if I call the token, will the task end, then a next task will start which checks if the Db left anything and logs an error if not? By the way, thanks for your time.... I found this, which may be a bit more verbose version of what you are saying. [TPL Cancellation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx)

Comment: @Miguelito As I've said several times.  There's no way to *actually* cancel the task.  No matter what you do, it's going to continue on doing whatever it is programmed to do.  There is no stopping it.  The only thing that you can do is continue on with your program, doing other things, while the operation is still chugging along in its unstoppable attempt to query the database.  The only possible way for the operation to *actually* be stopped, is for the database API to support it.  Either it does, or it doesn't.  You have to live with that, or write your own from scratch.

Comment: OK, then what happens to that task? My application is timer driven, so when it sees that that Task/Thread is past the maximum time, it will log it as an error and go on to the next job. You seem to agree that there is no such thing as Task.Abort(). So I might as well stick with threads rather than Tasks. Should I ignore the phantom thread since the object who's method it is running is long gone or should I use Thread.Abort(), catch the exception and do a Join()? I guess I could display the count of Db Fails/Dead Threads on the dashboard.

Comment: @Miguelito Thread.Abort doesn't *actually* cancel this operation either.  In *neither* case are you *actually* cancelling anything.  You *think* that you are.  It gives you the false impression that you are, but you aren't.  The operation is still continuing on in either case, you're simply executing whatever code you had planned to run when it finished even though it's not done.  Using `Abort` introduces a whole mess of possible bugs and hard to use code with *no* improved functionality.

Comment: Fascinating. I knew that Abort() was considered evil. So you seem to be saying to just log the hangup at timeout and forget the Thread/Task. Actually, as written, it raises an event, so if that event ever does happen, I should log it too. I'm testing the code at the link I gave that does what you say and the behavior is a mess. Thank you again.

Comment: @Servy, this `WithCancellation` won't propagate cancellation if the original task gets cancelled internally first, [like this](http://dotnetfiddle.net/ksYCGc). You actually point that out yourself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22543052/1768303).

Comment: @Noseratio Correct.  The whole *point* here is that the original task doesn't support cancellation.  You wouldn't be using this on a task that *does* support cancellation, so there isn't any need *to* support it.  It was an intentional decision not to support propagating cancellation here.

Answer (score 1):

You have several other options for your thread cancellation. For example, your thread could make an asynchronous database call and then wait on that and on the cancellation token. For example:

```
// cmd is a SqlCommand object
// token is a cancellation token
IAsyncResult ia = cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();  // starts an async request

WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[]{token.WaitHandle, ia.AsyncWaitHandle};
var ix = WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles);
if (ix == 0)
{
    // cancellation was requested
}
else if (ix == 1)
{
    // async database operation is done. Harvest the result.
}
```

There's no need to throw an exception if the operation was canceled. And there's no need for `Thread.Abort`.

This all becomes much cleaner with `Task`, but it's essentially the same thing. `Task` handles common errors and helps you to do a better job fitting all the pieces together.

You said:

> TPL is just a nice wrapper for a Thread, so I see absolutely nothing a Task can do that a Thread cannot. It's just done differently.

That's true, as far as it goes. After all, C# is just a nice wrapper for an assembly language program, so I see absolutely nothing a C# program can do that I can't do in assembly language. But it's a whole lot easier and faster to do it with C#.

Same goes for the difference between TPL or Tasks, and managing your own threads. You can do all manner of stuff managing your own threads, or you can let the TPL handle all the details and be more likely to get it right.